# bar graph with horizontal reference line in front

Tags: graph, stata

I am trying to create a bar graph where I need to put reference lines for specific y values. I can do this with yline as:

```
graph bar libdem, over(country, sort(libdem) descending label(alternate)) ///
bar(1, color(gs10) lcolor(black) lwidth(medium)) ytitle("") yline(.3864677, lstyle(foreground)) ///
title("Liberal Democracy") ylabel(,gstyle(minor)) legend(off)
```

resulting in:
[image]

the problem is that the reference line is in the background and not visible enough. It would be nice to have it in the foreground, overlaid on the bars. I tried `lstyle`, but it did not do the trick. I saw [this post](http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1344635-adding-a-horizontal-line-to-a-graph-bar) on something similar, but the problem is I could not figure out how to make `||` work with `over`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code from the Statalist post you linked to

```
sysuse auto, clear

collapse mpg, by(rep78)

twoway bar mpg rep78, base(0) barw(0.6) || function y = 23, ra(0.7 5.3) ///
yla(0(5)40) legend(off) ytitle(Mean miles per gallon) xtitle(`: var label rep78')
```

and here's the proof that it works: 
[image]

You don't provide a reproducible example and don't indicate explicitly what code you tried to add a horizontal line. But possible problems are evident:

1. The device above won't work with `graph bar`. You do need to use `twoway bar` instead.
2. Before you do that you will need to `collapse libdem, by(country)` to get a dataset with means.

-- which are why the example was phrased as it was.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! the problem is that once I do twoway bar, I need to specify more than one variable to plot. In the `over(country)` Stata knew, that I wanted the value on libdem over the country. twoway bar treats country as a continuous numeric variable, I lose my value labels, etc. I am not sure how to provide a reproducible example without typing in my dataset...

Comment: Not so, so far as I can see. First of all, as the example makes plain, there is no `over()` option with `twoway bar`: the equivalent is specifying what goes on the _x_ axis. Second, `collapse` won't lose the value labels of numeric variables in `by()`. Third, you don't need to give your own dataset: as in my example you just need to use a dataset supplied with Stata to make your code reproducible. Alternatively, if your real problem is more complicated than you tell us, understood, but how are we supposed to know that?